# Using inherited in the "Create" constructor of an TObject

Tags: delphi

Rant: Should I call "inherited" in the constructor of a class derived from TObject or TPersistent?

```
constructor TMyObject.Create;
begin
 inherited Create;   // Delphi doc: Do not create instances of TPersistent. Use TPersistent as a base class when declaring objects that are not components, but that need to be saved to a stream or have their properties assigned to other objects.    
 VectorNames := TStringList.Create;
 Clear;
end;
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes. It does nothing, true, but it's harmless. I think there is value in being consistent about always calling the inherited constructor, without checking to see if there is, in fact, an implementation. Some will say that it's worth calling inherited Create because Embarcadero might add an implementation for TObject.Create in the future, but I doubt this is true; it would break existing code which does not call inherited Create. Still, I think it is a good idea to call it for the reason of consistency alone.

Comment: "It does nothing"??!! It initiates the basic object storage! And may do required stuff defined in a base class you're inheriting. Not calling it may result in the worst kind of errors and bugs: those that you don't find out what is going on rightaway.

Comment: IIRC, the basic storage is already allocated before your constructor (Create) is called.

Comment: mj2008, you are right. Stijn, you are wrong. Read the source!

Comment: I think the most important reason is the one Gamecat stated - at some point you may want to reparent your class from TObject to something else and new class may contain non-trivial constructor.

Comment: That is a special case of "be consistent," but I agree, I like the way he put it.

Comment: @Stijn, the constructor of TObject does nothing, allocating storage is done by NewInstance, initalizing by InitInstance. Both class methods of TObject.

Comment: But don't call inherited on methods that override abstract methods (or have stuff like Assert('Create must be overridden') in the base class!

Answer (score 13):

I always do this.

If you are refactoring and move code to a common ancestor, calling the inherited Create has the following advantages:

1. If the common ancestor has a constructor, you can't forget to call it.
2. If the common ancestor has a constructor with different parameters, the compiler warns you for this.

Comment: Although Craig is right offcourse, these are also my main reasons to call inherited Create, more so than being consistent.

Answer (score 3):

You can also override "procedure AfterConstruction". This procedure is always called, no matter what kind of constructor.

```
public
  procedure AfterConstruction; override;
end;

procedure TfrmListBase.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  //your stuff, always initialized, no matter what kind of constructor!
end;
```

For example: if you want to create an object with a different constructor than the normal TObject.Create, such as TComponent.Create(AOwner) or a custom (overloaded) constructor, you can get problems because your override is not called and (in this case) your "VectorNames" variable will be nil.

Comment: If your overridden constructor isn't called, then it's a bug in your descendant class. That's a problem for the descendant-class developer to worry about, not you. And it IS possible to skip a call to AfterConstruction, for the same reason you can skip a call to the constructor: The descendant provides its own implementation and neglects to call the inherited method.

Comment: Rob: If you make a factory class, which generates TObject descendants, you cannot use TObject.Create() because it is not virtual! And if you make a TComponent descendant in your factory: it has a different constructor (Create(AOwner)). That's why you should use AfterConstruction: it is always called, no matter what kind of constructor

Answer (score 2):

I call it, except when i need a very optimized constructor.

Comment: You need to post this as a comment, not as an answer. The answers must be complete AND well documented. Yours is none of this.

Comment: What? Optimized constructors don't need to call "inherited" ? :)